# how to retrieve "seen by" data for group post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to this [How to get the Seen By data for group post on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667448/how-to-get-the-seen-by-data-for-group-post-on-facebook) , this wasn't  possible 4 months ago, there's any solution now ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK There still isn't any way to get this. It would probably have some huge privacy implications, I wouldn't hold my breath on them implementing it any time soon.